# How do i install mods on rigs of rods?

Tags: 12.10, games

How to install additional cars and maps on rigs of rods? I install game from ppa and want install additional cars and maps. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete instruction on this game, it's really simple, just unpack files in the specified directory:

[installing files from repo. for pre 0.36 ver.](http://www.rigsofrods.com/wiki/pages/Installing_Files_from_the_Repository_pre_0.36)

[installing files from repo for post 0.36 ver.](http://www.rigsofrods.com/wiki/pages/Installing_Files_from_the_Repository_post_0.36)

Comment: I can't find ~/RigsofRods/packs folder. I am read this tutorial.

Comment: which version of the game is installed?